# liferay: how to perform autologin programatically (hooks or own portlet doesn't matter)

Tags: liferay, autologin

I'm using an external token service to validate my users and they then get redirected to the portal (portal url + some get parameters). NOTE: this service is in no other way connected to my portal, and it isn't amongst the supported SSO list of liferay.

Now since I (have to) use this external method for this I also have to set a default password.
However I've yet to find how to force an autologin (whether through a hooking system or plain classes/filters doesn't really matter to me).

The liferay wiki is quite scarce on information and posting a question just results in "look at class x" which really doesn't help me at all..

Comment: What is the maven part of this question? Are you sure it's going to attract the right people with the current tag?

Comment: For some reason new question openened an old question including text and tags, I forgot to change the tags. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost answer it youself: You need to implement com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AutoLogin interface, put the JAR with implementation to classpath and add classname to the portal-ext.properties under auto.login.hooks key.

Be very carefull as this security stuff is always very risky and it's easy to open a new security hole.

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.2/javadocs/portal-service/com/liferay/portal/security/auth/AutoLogin.html